# Using jquery to modify css when in mobile view (>720px)

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

On the 2nd page of my codepen project website, I have a jquery event which makes a little blurb slide open to the right when in views larger than 720px wide.

I am trying to make the "click to slide right" thing disappear when width is less than 720px. However on initial load of page, the blurb is showing and clicking in the area doesn't seem to work. Also when I make the browswer small as possible, the "click to slide" disappears along with the blurb, but doesn't come back when I resize to full screen. What am I doing wrong here?

Note I know now how to fix this issue using a media query, but I want to see if I can implement it in my jQuery script without having to change it in css.

Advice?

[codepen project from freecodecamp](http://codepen.io/max77p/pen/JGQNVg)

jquery:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 720) {
        $("#flip").hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        $(".lead").hide(function(){
$("#flip").click(function(){
  $(".lead").toggle('slide','right',500);
 });
    }); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
// Your responsive logic
var myResize = function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 720) {
       $("#flip").hide();
    }else{
       $(".lead").hide();
       $("#flip").show();
    }
};
// Execute it every resize
$(window).resize(myResize);
$(myResize); // Execute it on ready as well
// Keep the click event handlers outside so they get defined once
$("#flip").click(function(){
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > 720) {
        $(".lead").toggle('slide','right',500);
    }
});
```

Comment: this is perfect! looks like i was on the right path, but I didn't cover some key points in my code..looks like to be another thing to work on. At least good to know i was on right path. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries! You had pretty much all the important pieces

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
<script>
   if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 720px)").matches) {
   /*  Code to execute */
  } else {
   /*  Code to execute */
  }
</script>
```

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1500-matchmedia-javascript-media-queries.html).

Comment: This only gets executed once, not every resize. Also, the tutorial you linked to is in French...not really the best for S.O.